# How to implement authentication for mobile Django client based upon JqueryMobile, AngularJs, PhoneGap

Tags: django, authentication, jquery-mobile, angularjs

I'm trying to create a one-site mobile app using AngularJS and jquerymobile, deploying it as a "native" app using [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/). The one-page navigation is build up similar to this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E86M9/3/), using jquerymobiles `data-role="page"` for in-page navigation.

```
<div id="page-1" data-role="page">..some content for page one</div>
<div id="page-2" data-role="page">..some content for page two</div>
```

The app should provide a login screen to the user. After a successful login the user is able to access the rest of the app.

The app is the mobile companion for a Django driven web portal. Regarding the web portal things are straight forward. I log the user in and check on the server whether the user is allowed to access a certain view.

For the mobile client I'm a bit lost. Do I have to implement some kind of tokken authentication? How can I get the `csrf` token into my `angularjs` scripts to do some ajax calls (GET and POST) to my backend? How can I refresh `page-1` independent from `page-2`? I would look for some hints where to start and what to take care off.

Answer (score 2):

We’ve the following :

[Client {JQM}/{PhoneGap}] ← REST → [Web-Server]—[Django/[Social-Auth](https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth)]

When DeviceReady and JQM are fully initialized, client issues GET to the server to test if it is already authenticated.

If yes, go to starting page; otherwise, go to log-in page. Then it is just normal authentication flow. Once it is authenticated, route to starting page.

Hope this help.

We did set cors in the client

```
$( document ).bind( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.support.cors = true;
    $.mobile.allowCrossDomainPages = true;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Could you maybe some more details / source code. Quite hard to imagine how this all works together. I just found a very interesting/sophisticated approach implemented in AngularJS. http://www.frederiknakstad.com/authentication-in-single-page-applications-with-angular-js/ I'm thinking about to convert it into a PhoneGap structure..

Comment: @Tom Just took a look at the link that you provided.  It is more or less the same approach that we did.  Since we are using backbone.marionette and Django/Social-Auth, so the specifics are different but the overall approach is the same as what we did.